# Empty folder is created in 7Zip while compressing file in java

Tags: java, 7zip

I am using Java compression API (java.util.ZIP package) to compress the files. It works well. However, I have below small issue.

Suppose my input file is `C:\temp\text.txt` and my output (compressed) file is `C:\temp\text.zip`

When I view the compressed file (text.zip) using WinZip it is shown correctly with the inner folder structure. It is shown as `temp\text.txt`. But if the same file is opened with 7Zip (using right click -> 7Zip -> Open archive option) it shows an empty folder after `C:\temp\text.zip\`. To view the `text.txt` I need to enter `C:\temp\text.zip\\\temp\` in 7Zip address bar. Notice the double backslash `\\\` here.

Below is my code:

```
String input="C:\temp\text.txt";
String output="C:\temp\text.zip";
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(output);
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
out.setMethod(ZipOutputStream.DEFLATED); //Entries can be added to a ZIP file in a compressed (DEFLATED) form 
out.setLevel(this.getZIPLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION));

File file = new File(input);
final int BUFFER = 2048;
byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
BufferedInputStream origin = null;
FileInputStream fi;

fi = new FileInputStream(file);
origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

int index = file.getAbsolutePath().indexOf(":") + 1;
String relativePath = file.getPath().substring(index);

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(relativePath);
out.putNextEntry(entry);
int count;
while((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
      out.write(data, 0, count);
}
origin.close();
out.close();
```

Can someone tell me why I see additional empty folder using 7Zip? I am using JDK7.

Comment: Should you not use "c:\\temp\\text.txt" instead?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try fixing this:

```
String input = "C:\\temp\\text.txt";
String output = "C:\\temp\\text.zip";
```

Notice that you need to escape the `\` char in a String. Given that `"\t"` is a valid escape sequence it might have worked before, but with a couple of tab characters thrown in the middle of the name. To avoid the need to escape the path separator you can write it like this:

```
String input = "C:/temp/text.txt";
String output = "C:/temp/text.zip";
```

And to make it a bit more portable, you can replace both `"\\"` and `"/"` with `File.separator`, a constant which holds the correct system-dependent name-separator for your environment (the `"C:"` part won't be portable, though.)

Comment: Lopez: Yes, '\t' is escape sequence. I already tried to escape that with '\', but it doesn'tt work. I also tried with forward slash '/' but it doesn't work either. The thing is the file is correctly compressed and viewed with WinZip (using C:\temp\text.txt and even using '\\') but not with 7Zip. So I doubt there may be different mechanism/algorithm 7Zip uses to compress the files or show it in 7Zip UI. Any idea?